# Ran netbeans IDE with sudo from the terminal

Tags: command-line, sudo, netbeans, read-only

I ran netbeans through the terminal with sudo and now everytime I open it I get this message:

[image: Netbeans message]

it also takes longer to load.

Comment: Why in the *world* are you running an IDE as root? Do you get this error if you run it as a regular user? Is this on Ubuntu or the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: I ran it once to see if this would solve another issue which I have already resolved. Yes, this warning is as a regular user. Ubuntu and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ran it with `sudo`, you caused it to change the ownership of its config files to root. This is a [common problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/85695) when running graphical programs with sudo.

The fix is simple enough, just change the ownership back. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo chown -R mario:mario /home/mario/.netbeans
```